# Can I change the volume/mute the microphone from foxpro?

Tags: foxpro, microphone

I have been reading examples in other programming languages for a couple of days now but I haven't managed to translate them into visual foxpro. Has anyone done it before and could provide me with a working example?
Thank you!

Comment: I've seen some code, and its somewhat ugly to try to retro to VFP.  Would you be able to work with a C# dll hook that is directly callable from VFP?

Comment: Yes but I have not found any and I don't know C# although I am planning to start learning it when I have the time.

Comment: I'll see if I can cook something up tonight and send you source code... If so, I'll give you my email then via comment.

Comment: That would be great, thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Checkout following function in Foxpro,

```
DECLARE INTEGER waveOutSetVolume IN winmm;
    INTEGER hwo,;
    INTEGER dwVolume
```

Also check the documentation here,

http://www.news2news.com/vfp/?group=-1&function=675

I hope it helps.

Comment: From what I understand that function changes the wave volume, not the microphone volume and there is no waveinsetvolume

Answer (score 0):

For Windows Vista and up, audio device *volume/mute* -- that includes both *playback* and *recording* devices (e.g. *microphone*) -- can be set via calling methods of several Windows Core Audio interfaces. Examples are [IAudioEndpointVolume::SetMute](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd368064%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) and IAudioEndpointVolume::SetMasterVolumeLevel.

While one cannot call these methods directly from Visual FoxPro, it is possible to wrap this functionality in FLL or in ActiveX control. The former of which I developed in November 2013.

This is how to mute the default recording device.

```
SET LIBRARY TO AudioDeviceLib.fll 
adl_SetOperationScope(0) && global volume
adl_SetFlowMode(1) && recording device
adl_SetMute(.T.) && mutes the device
```

This is how to set the default recording device's volume to 50%.

```
adl_SetVolume(0.5)
```

[The described FLL library](http://www.news2news.com/vfp/?solution=13) also allows enumerating audio devices, getting and setting the default device, getting and setting volume and mute states, operates with channels, and plays WAV sounds.

While the library is not a freeware, its demo version is fully functional. Again please note that it requires at least Windows Vista to run.